# A problem with a limit of two variables

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find out this limit, if it exists. If yes, what is its value? If not, how do I show?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin^{⁻1}(y)+\cos^{-1}(x)}{xy}$$

I tried the few ways I know, like setting $y = x$, but failed.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sin^{-1}(x)$? $\frac{1}{\sin x} $ or $\arcsin x$? Anyway, note that your function is not defined whenever $xy=0$, let alone in $x^2+y^2=0$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy It is $\frac{1}{\sin (x)}$